# Upload many files with BlackRaccoon

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ftp, blackraccoon

I try to upload many files to a ftp-server in a iOS-App

The following code works perfect without the loop , but when i add the loop, then the paths would be viewed correct with the new file name, but nothing is uploaded.

Only the last file is created on the ftp-server with marvel9.jpg, but the size is 0.

```
- (IBAction) uploadFile :(id)sender
{
    NSString *applicationDocumentsDir =          [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *filepath = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@/%@", applicationDocumentsDir, @"marvel.jpg"];
    InfoLog(@"%@", filepath);
    uploadData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile: filepath];

    uploadFile = [[BRRequestUpload alloc] initWithDelegate:self];
    uploadFile.hostname = host.text;
    uploadFile.username = username.text;
    uploadFile.password = password.text;


    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        uploadFile.path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/marvel%d.jpg", path.text, i];

        InfoLog(@"%@", uploadFile.path);

        [uploadFile start];
    }
}
```

Comment: Bummer, uploadData is neither defined nor used anywhere.

Comment: Bummer 2: Single BRRequestUpload used in the loop with path being hot-swapped. It does not seem right.